# SVG text not centering firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox, svg

I have a SVG logo with text, text is centered.
And this works fine in chrome and IE but not firefox, the text is slightly moved to the left.

```
<text transform="matrix(0.9287 0 0 1 60.9023 137.7646)">
    <tspan x="0" y="0" fill="#FFFFFF" stroke="#FAFAF8" stroke-miterlimit="10" font-family="'Consolas'" font-size="71.5163" letter-spacing="9.691">SOC</tspan>
    <tspan x="-24.809" y="85.819" fill="#FFFFFF" stroke="#FAFAF8" stroke-miterlimit="10" font-family="'Consolas'" font-size="71.5163" letter-spacing="9.691">KING</tspan>
</text>
```

Please help.

Comment: Firefox has a different transform-origin basis. There are a number of questions related to this matter. - Check the Related Questions on the left.

Comment: Ok, thanks will take a look at the related. Hopefully I will find something there.

Comment: Firefox does not yet support the letter-spacing CSS property on SVG text.

Comment: @Robert yep, you're right it's the letter-spacing property. I tried font-kerning="inherit/ auto/ normal/ none" and textLength="" at various sizes, worked in chrome not in firefox. In the end I removed the letter spacing property and adjusted my x and y. I will maybe try again later.

Comment: kerning is obsolete and will be dropped in SVG 2. textLength works, but only on text elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK so I came up with a work around to get letter spacing the same in both chrome and firefox. What I did was add both to text-transform: letter-spacing="9.691" textLength="780px" and adjusted the x until both browsers displayed the text in the center of the image. Its not pretty but it works.

```
 <text transform="matrix(0.9287 0 0 1 60.9023 137.7646)" letter-spacing="9.691" textLength="780px" font-weight="bold">
        <tspan x="1" y="0" fill="#FFFFFF" font-family="'Consolas'" font-size="71.5163">SOC</tspan>
        <tspan x="-21.8" y="85.819" fill="#FFFFFF" font-family="'Consolas'" font-size="71.5163">KING</tspan>
    </text>
```

Answer (score 2):

use `text-anchor="middle"` to center the text (then its x coordinate points to the center)

Comment: text-anchor="middle" works in chrome (adjust x value) middle chrome != middle firefox. Tried adding in <text> & <tspan> tags. And then when I try to letter-space or textLength - I get it right (changing the x value) in chrome, IE but not firefox. My question is how to letter space (kerning) SVG text in firefox.

<text transform="matrix(0.9287 0 0 1 60.9023 137.7646)">
    <tspan x="73" y="0" text-anchor="middle" fill="#FFFFFF" font-family="'Consolas'" font-size="71.5163">SOC</tspan>
    <tspan x="69.8" y="85.819" fill="#FFFFFF" font-family="'Consolas'" font-size="71.5163">KING</tspan>
</text>